# Symfony : How to disable the routing system on other folders

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, url-rewriting, url-routing

I'm using `Symfony` for my new website but I have a problem : I can't seem to be able to access the forum anymore.

These are my folders on my server:

[image: server organization]

I found a solution but it doesn't work well - in my .htaccess (location: /website/web/) I put this:

```
RewriteRule ^(ddl|phpmyadmin|forum)($|/) - [L]
```

With SymLinks for forum, ddl and phpmyadmin in `/website/web/`

With this solution, I can see the forum but I can't access to the upload system because of the URL : `http://www.website.fr/forum/upload/`

Is there a solution to access `http://www.website.fr/fichiers/` or `http://www.website.fr/forum/` without the routing system of Symfony?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... I just had to add index.php at the end of the URL and it works now. But this system with SymLinks is weird.